# Uploading multiple files with user entered name

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I want to upload multiple files with user entered names. For single file i can change the name like this

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="name">File Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="filename" class="form-control" required /> 
        <input type="file" name="file" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

submit.php

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //insert query to db
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/quotes/".$filename.".".$extension."");
}
```

This is working for single image.

But for multiple images i have give 5 file upload options in the form like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="file2">File Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="filename2" class="form-control"  />
    <input type="file" name="file2">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="file3">File Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="filename32" class="form-control"  />
    <input type="file" name="file3">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="file4">File Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="filename4" class="form-control"  />
    <input type="file" name="file4">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="file5">File Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="filename5" class="form-control"  />
    <input type="file" name="file5">
</div>
```

i want to give the filename so i am using this method instead of

```
<input type="file[]" multiple name="file">
```

But here any of the files/file names can be blank except 1st upload . So how do i insert into database and upload to the desire folder. 
everytime do i need to check whether the filename is blank/file before uploading? Please suggest

or is there any way to change the name of each file in `<input type="file[]" multiple name="file">` method?

Comment: use the same name for each file field and also same for the text field - using `[]` style syntax. ie `name="file[]"` & `name="filename[]"` - you should have an indexed array when the form is submitted and can access file and name based upon this index

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of what I tried, but obviously failed, to explain regarding the names. If you run this you will see output similar to what follows:

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );

    function pre( $data ){
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($data,true)); 
    }


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        pre($_POST);
        pre($_FILES);
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class='form-label'>File Name</label>
                <input type='text' name='filename[]' class='form-control'  />
                <input type='file' name='file[]'>
            </div>

            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class='form-label'>File Name</label>
                <input type='text' name='filename[]' class='form-control'  />
                <input type='file' name='file[]'>
            </div>

            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class='form-label'>File Name</label>
                <input type='text' name='filename[]' class='form-control'  />
                <input type='file' name='file[]'>
            </div>

            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class='form-label'>File Name</label>
                <input type='text' name='filename[]' class='form-control'  />
                <input type='file' name='file[]'>
            </div>

            <input type='submit' />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The typical output:

```
Array
(
    [filename] => Array
        (
            [0] => borat
            [1] => mouse
            [2] => thumbs
            [3] => suspense
        )

)
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2480-1653-2.3558884.jpg.gallery.jpg
                    [1] => 84679948.jpg
                    [2] => CBUESFMUsAAM534.jpg
                    [3] => FullThrottle.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7.2\uploadtemp\php3719.tmp
                    [1] => C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7.2\uploadtemp\php371A.tmp
                    [2] => C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7.2\uploadtemp\php371B.tmp
                    [3] => C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7.2\uploadtemp\php371C.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 43124
                    [1] => 80518
                    [2] => 58358
                    [3] => 68344
                )

        )

)
```

From that you can use the array indices to link a file to the corresponding text

Comment: Will try, but if any of the filename is blank but file is uploaded, what should be done in this scenario? and also how to skip the blank options?

Comment: how you process the array is essentially your choice but you can test using `!empty( $var )` to determine what to do. One thing you could do in javascript would be to add event listeners to each `file` input field - if they change (ie: the user chooses a file ) then ensure that the previous `text` field has an `required` attribute set or disable the submit button until the text field has some content. Admittedly these steps can be bypassed fairly easily but for legitimate users could help them.